# Which implicit conversions in Scala are present as default when nothing is imported

Tags: scala, implicits, implicit-conversion

Which implicits are present by default in Scala?

I know of **RichString**, **Regex** and some others I use.

- But is there a list of them all?
- Where are they implemented ? SourceFiles?
- Is there a way to get a list of all possible implicit conversions for the current state of imports ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatically imported members are:

- The members of the `java.lang` package
- The members of the `scala`  package
- The members of the `Predef` object

See The scala specification §9.1

Given that only objects (and package objects) can contain methods or values, the only place where standard (with no additional import) implicit values can be found  is in `Predef` (the `scala` package does not seem to have a corresponding package object at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

I believe all scala default imports are located in [scala.Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Predef%24), including implicits.

Answer (score 0):

Everything declared in Predef is imported automatically including implicits. 
Check Predef at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Predef.
There you can see a list of value members. You should look for items starting with `implicit def`.